# Can't sort values before plotting

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Here is what I'm trying to do: I currently have the below plot

```
x=frequencia['Numero']
y=frequencia['Recorrencia']
plt.bar(x,y)
```

[image]

I'm trying to plot the first 10 highest values. For that, I can sort my DataFrame with

```
frequencia.sort_values(by=['Recorrencia'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
```

But if I try to print the first 10 values using `.head(10)`, all I get is this second plot.

[image]

Is there a way to plot it like below instead?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: `frequencia = frequencia.sort_values(by=['Recorrencia'])`

Then extract the x, y variables to be plotted:

```
x=frequencia['Numero']
y=frequencia['Recorrencia']
plt.bar(x,y)
```

Comment: Just figured it out. It wasn't plotting properly because the dtype was **int**. I changed it to **str** and if ran without issues.